# Zend_Db_Table_Row instance form Zend_Auth

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-auth

I use `Zend_Auth` and `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable` in my project. I want to get a `Zend_Db_Table_Row` instance from the `Zend_Auth` adapter (`Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable`). I haven't found any good solution. I need a `Zend_Db_Table_Row` instance because I use own row class in which I have a method to get data from dependent table.

I know that I can get this data once again but it makes no sense because this data was already fetched from the database by `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is putting the row into a Zend_Auth_Storage container. By overriding Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface::authenticate(), you can do just that.

```
/**
 * Authenticate
 *
 * Overriding to provide more information about the authenticated user
 *
 * @return Zend_Auth_Result
 */
public function authenticate()
{
    $result = parent::authenticate();

    //  Store row on success
    if ($result->getCode() == Zend_Auth_Result::SUCCESS) {
        return new Zend_Auth_Result(
            $result->getCode(),
            $this->getResultRowObject(null, array('*')),
            $result->getMessages()
        );
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable` fetches only those fields, which stored in users table ([`getResultRowObject()`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.dbtable.html#zend.auth.adapter.dbtable.advanced.storing_result_row)). I think it's more expedient is instancing 
your Row class (or User class) with data provided by `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable`

Look here for similar question: [In Zend_Auth, can I get a domain-model User object instead of stdClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272683/in-zend-auth-can-i-get-a-domain-model-user-object-instead-of-stdclass)